(anydesk:364592): GdkGLExt-WARNING **: 11:53:44.324: Window system doesn't support OpenGL -ubuntu
I'm trying to use anydesk on my ubuntu pc but I get the following error,
(anydesk:364592): GdkGLExt-WARNING **: 11:53:44.324: Window system doesn't support OpenGL.

How can I fix this issue, but previously It's worked fine.
i have updated my kernal by using this
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-22.04

now my kernel is 6.8.0-40-generic. but still same issue happened when I try to run anydesk.
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy


6.6.8-060608-generic
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy @guiverc

Please do not put info for a question into the comments. Edit the question and add and format the info there.

i have updated my kernal by using this "sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-22.04"
now my kernal is 6.8.0-40-generic.
but still same issue happened when I try to run anydesk.

all the details are added.

Where did you get the anydesk app from and how was it installed?

I have get it from official website , previously its worked but now it hasn't work
